# Change form action depending on x-data select options in Alpine JS

Tags: forms, select, dropdown, action, alpine.js

DISCLAIMER: I am a newbie!

I would like to change the redirect of my form (that would be the action) depending on the selected city in my dropdown.
I use Alpine JS and the dropdown doesn't come as a list of "options" but as a list in a div with a x-data attribute.
I would like to add a simple JS script to my code to just put the selected city in the dropdown in a var and depending on the value of that var, change the address of the form action to redirect the visitor accordingly when they click the submit button.
I could manage to do it in vanilla js maybe, but in Alpine I don't know how to find the "value" of my select options. Suggestions welcome, and sorry, I am new to coding and am still struggling to understand the simple logics of coding, be aware!

Here is my code:

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="https://buy.stripe.com/">
                        
<div 
x-data="select({ data: { fr: 'Paris ', de: 'Berlin ', it: 'Bologna ', gb: 'London ', 'us': 'NY ', 'jp': 'Tokyo ' }, emptyOptionsMessage: 'No cities match your search.', name: 'country', placeholder: 'Select a city' })"
x-init="init()"
@click.away="closeListbox()"
@keydown.escape="closeListbox()"
>

<script>
function select(config) {
  return {
      data: config.data,

      emptyOptionsMessage: config.emptyOptionsMessage ?? 'No results match your search.',

      focusedOptionIndex: null,

      name: config.name,

      open: false,

      options: {},

      placeholder: config.placeholder ?? 'Select an option',

      search: '',

      value: config.value,

      closeListbox: function () {
          this.open = false

          this.focusedOptionIndex = null

          this.search = ''
      },

      focusNextOption: function () {
          if (this.focusedOptionIndex === null) return this.focusedOptionIndex = Object.keys(this.options).length - 1

          if (this.focusedOptionIndex + 1 >= Object.keys(this.options).length) return

          this.focusedOptionIndex++

          this.$refs.listbox.children[this.focusedOptionIndex].scrollIntoView({
              block: "center",
          })
      },

      focusPreviousOption: function () {
          if (this.focusedOptionIndex === null) return this.focusedOptionIndex = 0

          if (this.focusedOptionIndex <= 0) return

          this.focusedOptionIndex--

          this.$refs.listbox.children[this.focusedOptionIndex].scrollIntoView({
              block: "center",
          })
      },

      init: function () {
          this.options = this.data

          if (!(this.value in this.options)) this.value = null

          this.$watch('search', ((value) => {
              if (!this.open || !value) return this.options = this.data

              this.options = Object.keys(this.data)
                  .filter((key) => this.data[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
                  .reduce((options, key) => {
                      options[key] = this.data[key]
                      return options
                  }, {})
          }))
      },

      selectOption: function () {
          if (!this.open) return this.toggleListboxVisibility()

          this.value = Object.keys(this.options)[this.focusedOptionIndex]

          this.closeListbox()
      },

      toggleListboxVisibility: function () {
          if (this.open) return this.closeListbox()

          this.focusedOptionIndex = Object.keys(this.options).indexOf(this.value)

          if (this.focusedOptionIndex < 0) this.focusedOptionIndex = 0

          this.open = true

          this.$nextTick(() => {
              this.$refs.search.focus()

              this.$refs.listbox.children[this.focusedOptionIndex].scrollIntoView({
                  block: "nearest"
              })
          })
      },
  }
}
</script>

</div>

<div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" x-model="show" >
<label for="checkbox" x-text="show" >
By using our services you agree to the <a href=# class="underline">terms and conditions</a> of our platform
</label>

</div>


<button type="submit">Send &rarr;</button>
                                          
                                         
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your configuration, where the *form* is not part of the *select* object, one option can be to pass the form id to the *select()* function togheter with the other parameters:

```javascript
x-data="select({ formId: 'form1', /* other parameters */ })"
```

then you can save the id in an attribute and prepare another attribute where you will save the form reference:

```javascript
formId: config.formId,
form: null,
data: config.data,
. . .
```

and then save a reference to the form in that attribute in the *init()* function:

```javascript
this.form = document.getElementById(this.formId);
```

when you need to modify the *action attribute* you can simply do it in the *selectOption()* function:

```javascript
this.value = Object.keys(this.options)[this.focusedOptionIndex];

// adapt it to your needs, the city names should be stored separately
this.form.action = "the-url-you-want/" + this.options[this.value].slice(0, -4);
```

If you plan on always putting the *select* in a *form*, you can also get a reference to it in the *init()* function, like this:

```javascript
this.form = this.$root.closest("form");
```

avoiding passing the id of the form to the *select*